# CSS Hover effect with links not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I found [this example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/) and was able to duplicate it [here](http://www.iwebarea.net/hoverTest.htm).
The problem is that it works in all browsers except `IE8`.  Can someone please help in getting it to  work in `IE8` or do something similar.  I'll even take a `jQuery` solution.

I have 7 images that will be displayed in the body of a page and when a user rolls over an image, there should be 7 or 8 links that would appear.  Any ideas?

I will also be content with a `jQuery` solution too. Code below.  I copied and pasted the contents of the `CSS` file

**CSS**

```
<style>
.view {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.view img {
    display: block;
    position: relative
}
.view h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.view p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center
}
.view a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}




.view-first img { 
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7); 
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first h2 {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first p { 
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first a.info{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}




.view-first:hover img { 
    transform: scale(1.1);
} 
.view-first:hover .mask { 
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
.view-first:hover p {
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-first:hover a.info {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}                               
    </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<style type="text/css">
    @import url('hoverStyle.css');
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="view view-first">  
        <img alt="Year In Review" src="YearInReview.png" />
    <div class="mask"> 
    <h2>Title</h2> 
    <p>Your Text</p> 
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="info">Link 1</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="info">Link 2</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="info">Link 3</a> </li>
   </ul>
</div>  
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working perfectly right!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [IE8.js](http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/)

**Usage:** 
If you want to support browser IE7+ then integrate thise code into your head tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or if you downloaded it then you may use this code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
 <script src="ie7/IE7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can use **squish** to fix more of your problems. You can do that by adding another line after the 1st include:

```
 <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7-squish.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Or

```
 <script src="ie7/ie7-squish.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? It did not work. All the CSS appeared as text on the page. see   http://www.iwebarea.net/hoverTest.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sure, throw modernizr.js on the page, then add this style:

```
.no-boxshadow .view a.info:hover {
    outline: 5px solid #aaa;
}
```

Rinse, repeat, for the remaining css3 styles that IE8 doesn't support.

It won't look as nice, but then again, it's IE8.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of other issues your code has other than the hover effect in IE 8.  I only answered the question you asked. You do have to fix all the other stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

For IE8, you may want first make a css that it understands, then enhance your transitions effect if you really wishes too.
(i know difficult to say/hear, redo it , it is just an advise don't relay 100% on js for the basis)

http://liveweave.com/g4MLe2 (only editor online i found working with a genuine IE8 stand alone)

[image: screen from IE8] See what it's like in genuine IE8 :)

Comment: link update , so hover opacity is very similar IE8/others. transition was not my point from what i could see in a real IE8. no background, list bullets, too messy in fact ....

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of searching today, found a solution and tweaked it to meet my needs.  Here it is:
http://www.incg.nl/blog/2008/hover-block-jquery/example/animate_hover.html

Well, the code did not work exactly how I wanted because I could not add individual links to it it so I tweaked it and came up with this: View source on the following link:    http://www.iwebarea.net/hoverTest2.html